# Не получается удалить строки в DataFrame, содержащие отрицательные значения

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Можно найти много подобных вопросов, но не получилось по какой-то причине реализовать ни один вариант, и я хочу понять, в чем ошибка. Есть некоторый dataframe, который в моем коде имеет название operonn. Он состоит из двух столбцов - 'Residual' и  'Multiplicity'. Необходимо выбросить строки из двух столбцов, которые содержат отрицательные значения. Пробую

```
operond = operonn[(operonn[['Residual', 'Multiplicity']]>0)]
```

Выдается результат, все еще содержащий отрицательные значения. В чем моя ошибка?

```
 Residual   Multiplicity
 0  80      2
 1  1       1
 2  0       0
 3  549     0
 4  69      0
 5  278     2
 6  114     0
 7  749     2
 8  25      1
 9  375     0
10  88      1
11  867     0
12  -17     1
13  1625    2
14  59      2
15  37      1
16  12      0
17  12      0
18  3380    2
19   42     0
20  -1      2
```

Comment: Можете привести в вопросе небольшой воспроизводимый пример данных?

Comment: Беда в том, что на небольшом объеме данных это работает, а на большом - нет

Comment: Пример привел - см. в тексте вопроса

Comment: что вы хотите получить на выходе? какие строки должны отсутствовать в выходном DF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [46]: (operonn[['Residual', 'Multiplicity']]>=0).all(axis=1)
Out[46]:
0      True
1      True
2      True
3      True
4      True
5      True
6      True
7      True
8      True
9      True
10     True
11     True
12    False
13     True
dtype: bool

In [47]: operonn = operonn[(operonn[['Residual', 'Multiplicity']]>=0).all(axis=1)]

In [48]: operonn
Out[48]:
    Residual  Multiplicity
0         80             2
1          1             1
2          0             0
3        549             0
4         69             0
5        278             2
6        114             0
7        749             2
8         25             1
9        375             0
10        88             1
11       867             0
13      1625             2
```

Comment: Просто так на большом объеме данных это не работает. Получено, что нужно, только если перед этим вставить    operonn = operonn.head(len(operonn)-1), что странно

Comment: @jeckey, это решение не зависит от размера DF. Что значит не работает? Выдается ошибка, какая? Что выдаёт `operonn.iloc[-1]`?

Comment: нет, ошибки не выдается. DF остается в первоначальном состоянии, строки не выбрасываются.

Comment: @jeckey, покажите содержимое указанных столбцов для __последней__ строки

Comment: 4729 -2146039           2

Comment: @jeckey, можете выложить результат `operonn[['Residual', 'Multiplicity']].to_csv(r'c:/temp/file.csv')` на любой свободный файлообменник?

Comment: я только нашел ошибку - там была опечатка в коде до этого, и в полном выводимом DF встречались числа в квадратных скобках. Спасибо за помощь